# Adding column to pyodbc list

Tags: python, pyodbc

I'm trying to add a column to a list returned from the fetchall() method in pyodbc, but it is giving me an error.  Here is my code:

```
import pyodbc
import time
import calendar
from datetime import date

#variable declaration
today = date.today()
beginRange = date(today.year,today.month,1)
endRange = date(today.year,today.month,2) #limit data to 2 days for testing

#connect to database
connJobDtl = pyodbc.connect("DSN=Global_MWM;UID=Master")
cJobDtl = connJobDtl.cursor()

#database query
cJobDtl.execute("select job,suffix,seq,date_sequence,[...]")
dataJobDtl = cJobDtl.fetchall()
cJobDtl.close()

#add another column to the list, date_sequence formatted to YYYY-MM
dataJobDtl = [x + [x[3].strftime("%Y-%m")] for x in dataJobDtl]
```

I'm getting this error when I run the script:

> ```
> File "...\jobDetailScript.py", line 23, in <module>
>   dataJobDtl = [x + [x[3].strftime("%Y-%m")] for x in dataJobDtl]
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'pyodbc.Row' and 'list'
> ```

As a test, I created a representative example in a Python shell and it worked fine, but I manually created a list of lists rather than generating a list from fetchall().  How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems fairly straightforward - as the error message states you're trying to `+` two different types of objects.  If you just cast the rows as lists it should work, so from my own ad-hoc testing:

```
>>>cur.execute('<removed>') #one of my own tables
>>>tmp = cur.fetchall()
>>>type(tmp[0]) #this is KEY!  You need to change the type

<type 'pyodbc.Row'>

>>>tt = [1,2,3]
>>>tmp[0] + tt #gives the same error you have

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
tmp[0] + tt
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'pyodbc.Row' and 'list'

>>>list(tmp[0]) + tt  #returns a list as you wanted

[14520496, ..., 1, 2, 3]
```